# Sqoop commands do not execute

Tags: eval, sqoop

I am practicing sqoop import and eval commands. But i cant execute any of the commands. Whenever i hit enter after writing a command, it just goes to the next line. I had to Ctrl + C to come out of it.

This is the command that i am trying to execute and it does not execute when i hit enter:

```
sqoop eval --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db--username retail_dba --password cloudera --query "select * from departments"
>
>
```

I tried restarting the cloudera manager but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing double quotes(`"`) for `--connect` tag:

Use this:

`sqoop eval --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" --username retail_dba --password cloudera --query "select * from departments"`